# The number of bits of a product of two decimal numbers

Tags: inequality, computational-complexity, binary

**Theorem.** Let us have two numbers $m,n\in\mathbb Z^+$ with $k$ and $l$ bits respectively where $k≥l$. Then $m\cdot n$ has either $k+l-1$ or $k+l$ bits.

Proof. Trivially follows from exponent rules.
$$2^{k+l-2}=2^{k-l}\cdot 2^{l-1}≤mn<2^k2^l=2^{k+l}$$

---

According to this proof, it seems like $mn$ should actually have $k+l-1$ or $k+l-2$ bits... is there a mistake in this proof, or am I misunderstanding something? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $m$ has $k$ bits and satisfies $2^{k-1}\le m < 2^k$. How many bits do you think the two bounds $2^{k+l-2}$ and $2^{k+l}$ have?

Comment: A recent question: [the smallest $k$-bit number is $2^{k-1}$ and the largest is $2^k-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4821087/89922).